# Data-table builtin buttons fixed place

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using an ajax datatable and while scrolling to the right, the builtin buttons like export, copy etc., don't stick to their original positions. How to make them fixed in their place and freely scroll the content of the datatable.

I tried:

```
.dt-buttons pull-right'{
position: fixed;}
```

and also:

```
position:sticky
```

in the ajax call of the datatable but that didn't work out either.

Also, I tried to remove that class and adding a new one but in doing so, the buttons stopped working.

```
$('.dt-buttons').removeClass('dt-buttons').addClass('dt-buttons pull-right 
style="position:fixed;right:148px;top:197px"')
```

EDIT-->
Achieved so by using

```
$('.dt-buttons').removeClass('dt-buttons').addClass("dt-buttons pull-right").css({"position":"fixed"});
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The latest edit in my code helped me get through it but on using position:fixed, the column visibility is not working although rest buttons are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this

```
"scrollX": true
```

It worked for me